# WiFi driver is not installed on Asus PCE AC68?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, asus

I am not able to install wireless card driver on Ubuntu? I tried to install it manually but not able to install?

Comment: All the commands here will not work until you turn off your secure boot from boot menu. This prevents system from installing drivers

Answer (score 13):

Sorry that I have to add this as an answer, as I don't have rep to comment yet.
Thanks to chili555 reply and racar comment I now have the PCE-AC68 working on my system, Ubuntu 15.04 on mobo ASUS A88XM-A by

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
sudo reboot
```

I wanted the card as I've upgraded my cable modem + wifi router to Telstra Gateway Max (rebadged Netgear) which supports dual band wifi. Link speeds specified as 216/292 Mbps. It's probably not ideally set up yet as I'm only getting about 30 Mbps - I note that it's 802.11abg connection from iwconfig:

```
wlan1     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Telstra226B"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 40:5D:82:47:F4:66   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

But at least it is working now, and faster than my old Netgear WN111 usb plugin :) So thank you again.

Answer (score 8):

Please run the command:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your device this?

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev
>   03)

If so, it uses the driver bcmwl-kernel-source.  If you still have the install DVD or USB, then you can find it and its prerequisite there. Navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop. Now navigate to pool > main > d > dkms and drag and drop dkms to your desktop. Now install both with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working. If it not as I described, please post your finding and I will edit my answer to propose a different solution.

Comment: Thanks, I found here the .deb file version 6.30.223.248 (http://ftp.psu.ru/linux/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/). And did exactly what you said, everything works fine now. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

Comment: since on the DVD i didn't find any drivers (only windows), i used sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman, and a scholar. You guard the night with your wisdom. You are ever so gentle, and perfect. But really THANK YOU!!! I thought all hope is lost! PPl on amazon were saying it wont work ever!

Answer (score 7):

I used this method:

Go to **Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**

It loads for a few minutes and then shows your wifi device (Broadcast name) and then you can enable it.

Then you can `sudo apt-get update`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install ndiswrapper

```
sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf
```

Check the driver is working:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
```

Load the module:

```
sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules
```

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi up and working!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I can't find a deb file for ndiswrapper-modules. So when i try to load the module, I will get the error "module ndiswrapper not found"

Comment: Full documentation is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same Wifi Adapter and got it to work as chili555 mentioned (could not comment yet). But on a default installation of Ubuntu there's a package missing which is mandatory. This is the DKMS package. So you need to install the DKMS package first before installing the driver package like Chilli555 explained.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Working on Ubuntu 14.10 and using the 5Ghz band it's performance is similar to what it is under Windows. On my internet connection I'm getting 200+ Mbit/s