# Using Wireless ASUS PCE-AC68 on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus, additional-drivers

I am having issue installing the driver of ASUS' PCE-AC68 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I have tried a few sources such as:

1. [WiFi driver is not installed on Asus PCE AC68?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596096/wifi-driver-is-not-installed-on-asus-pce-ac68)
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmXl6WsC3Kc

However, the problem I always face is that the command:  always had error.

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-79-generic (x86_64)
consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.40.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found
```

I'm not too sure what to do anymore and would really appreciate assistance in getting this to work.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of console messages, and instead just paste the text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version of bcmwl-kernel-source than what is in the trusty repositories for the 4.4 kernel

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb
```

If you have UEFI you will need to disable Secure Boot as this module is not signed

Reboot