# How can I install drivers when secure boot is enabled? Can I disable secure boot without messing up my dual boot (with Windows 10)?

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, secure-boot

I'm trying to install WiFi drivers. I read that I need to do a `sudo modprobe wl`, but then I get an error saying

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted`

Googling leads me to believe that this is because "secure boot" is enabled on my system. I can see it enabled in my BIOS settings (ASUS motherboard).

I am dual booting (unfortunately I need Windows 10 installed as well, for gaming), and I suspect that Windows 10 needs secure boot to be enabled? I don't know.

So my questions are

**a) How do I install the WiFi drivers, when secure boot is enabled?**

**b) If I need to disable secure boot, will that mess up my dual boot setup? Should my Windows 10 installation still work normally, if I disable secure boot?**

(If it's relevant, the device I need drivers for is ASUS AC68 WiFi adapter)

EDIT: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/704150/332138) is why I try to do `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: Is this a USB device? I doubt that wl is the correct driver.

Comment: No it's a "card" connected to the (PCI?) slot on my motherboard. https://www.asus.com/no/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/PCEAC68/

Comment: I think you have misdiagnosed your problem. Look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0` and see what is said about your hardware.

Comment: Let's have a look at: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @chili555 here's where I got the information that I need to do `sudo modprobe wl`: https://askubuntu.com/a/704150/332138

Comment: Manufacturers can and do change the chipset over the years. Again, may we see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: I'll paste the results of that command as soon as I'm back on the computer in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled secure boot, and the Windows installation did not suffer.